# Can sex with a prostitute be permissible if they become a temporary slave?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, slavery, sexuality

Can a prostitute be classed as "[ma malakat aymanakum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma_malakat_aymanukum)" (what your right hand possesses) as you through payment she becomes temporarily yours? Please provide clear evidences if possible.

Comment: Salam Bismillah Why with a prostitute , can't you marry , or what is wrong with you brother it is zina , is this the teaching of our prophet ,no , our prophet will cry on day of judgement for his umma , don't you understand prostitute are women too. They do not willingly do it go and watch some documentary on the darkness of this ,you will find out , this is clearly wrong

Answer (score 10):

Prostitution is considered haram in Islam.  (See [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=90336) for a fatwa on this.)

Sex outside of marriage ([zina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zina), or "fornication") is strongly and directly forbidden e.g. in [Qur'an 17:32](https://quran.com/17/32) (*...do not approach unlawful sexual intercourse...*) and in [Sahih al-Bukhari 6810](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6810) (*...the one who commits an illegal sexual intercourse is not a believer at the time of committing illegal sexual intercourse...*).

There's a prescribed hadd punishment when those involved are unmarried (*...lash each one of them with a hundred lashes...* [Qur'an 24:2](https://quran.com/24/2)) and a worse hadd punishment when those involved are married (*...stoned to death...* [Sunan Abi Dawud 4455](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/40/105) [grade: sahih]).

As for using slavery as a mechanism for making fornication halal:  Slavery is not considered possible today ([Dar Al-Ifta](http://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=6830)), and previously slavery was restricted to prisoners of war ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84431)). See also e.g. [Are Muslim men allowed to take “sex slaves?”](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/649/17163) and [Is voluntary slavery Islamic?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46545/17163)  As such, while in certain circumstances it is halal for a male to have sex with a female slave, one cannot simply "rent" a slave to have sex with them.

Answer (score 7):

Having intercourse with a prostitute is forbidden (even through legal means such as marriage) and makes the person who does it a prostitute as well.

> الزاني لا ينكح إلا زانية أو مشركة والزانية لا ينكحها إلا زان أو مشرك وحرم ذلك على المؤمنين
>
> The fornicator does not marry except a [female] fornicator or polytheist, and none marries her except a fornicator or a polytheist, and that has been made unlawful to the believers.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 24:3](https://quran.com/24/3)</sup>

A free person person can not "*become*" a slave through a contract; enslavement for a price is forbidden:

> قال الله ثلاثة أنا خصمهم يوم القيامة ... ورجل باع حرا
>
> Allah says: I will be against three persons on the Day of Resurrection: ... One who sells a free person (as a slave)
>
> <sup>—  [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/34/174)</sup>

Finally, a prostitute isn't your slave, but it is mere words that you say, the evidence is that you do not have real authority over her as you would over a slave. If she is a slave, Can you choose to not free her? Can you take something from her property? Can you choose to not pay her? Can you choose to make her work and give you income? Can you arrange her marriage with someone?

Answer (score -1):

**In the name of God, the Most Gracious, Most Merciful**

**All praise is due to God (ﷻ), the Lord of the Worlds. The Beneficent, the Merciful. Master of the Day of Judgement, and God’s Peace and Blessings be upon Muhammad (ﷺ), his family, his noble Companions, and all those who follow them.**

---

**Your question:** Is sex with prostitute permissible in Islam?

**Answer:** Having sex with a prostitute is forbidden because God Said:

> "Those who guard their chastity (ie. private parts, from illegal sexual acts) except from their wives or (the captives and slaves) that their right hands possess, - for them, they are free from blame."
>
> — [al-Mu’minoon 23:5-6]

———————

> ”And compel not your slave-girls to prostitution when they desire to keep chaste, in order to seek the frail goods of this world's life. And whoever compels them, then surely after their compulsion God is Forgiving, Merciful..”
>
> — Quran 24:33

Prostitution (trading sex for money) is haraam. If any does this then he shall be stoned to death. It was practiced by some Arabs during the 6th century. In the 7th century, Muhammad declared that prostitution is forbidden on all grounds.

prophet Muhammad said:

> O, you young men! I recommend marriage to you."
>   — The Wasaelush Shia **(vol. 14, p. 25)**

God Says:

> Do not go near adultery, surely it is an indecency, and an evil way [of fulfilling sexual urge]. **(17:32)**

So as you can understand from these verses is that once you have sex with a prostitute temporarily then you have committed the sin of Adultery. The best way is, go ahead and marry a woman and finish, problem solved. You won’t need anymore to commit Adultery.

**CONCLUSION:** You can have sex with a prostitute but you must ask her also if she is agreed for temporary period of time and this must be done after marriage, and not before marriage because it is considered Adultery.

---

**Sources:**

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_sexual_jurisprudence
2. https://www.al-islam.org/marriage-and-morals-islam-sayyid-muhammad-rizvi/chapter-three-islamic-sexual-morality-2-its
3. http://islaminitsownwords.blogspot.com/2009/04/does-islam-allow-prostitution.html

Comment: @Shadi Can you provide an evidence if you claim that it is permissible?

Comment: 4:24 is the verse for mutah. Temporary marriage, similar to prostitution. It was only temporary however. That’s the Sunni view. Shia still believe it’s acceptable.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I didn’t invented this, but I’ll look for it and then I’ll edit it one more time

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_sexual_jurisprudence

Comment: @Shadi Equating temporary marriage to prostitution seems offensive and provocative, especially w.r.t our Shia members. There are significant differences between the two, e.g. mutah requires the permission of a wali (guardian) , is an exclusive partnership for as long as it lasts, involves a period of purification (iddah) between different marriages, ascribes any child to the father and makes him responsible for it, including giving a share of inheritance etc.

Comment: "If you want this, then it is allowed for you to have sex with a prostitute when both of you are agreed for temporary period of time, but this must be done after marriage" — As Muslims, we are not allowed to marry prostitutes, temporarily or permanently. Also, the question is about prostitutes as right-hand possessions, not as wives.

Comment: @UmH AsSalam Aalykum. Women during early Islamic times would usually be financially dependent upon their _awliya'_ for their sustenance. Given that these days eve women are also financially independent like men, I heard someone argue these women do not have to seek the permission of their walis. What is your take on this matter?

Comment: @a_sid Claims need to be based on evidence. Otherwise anyone can pretend that various Islamic requirements are dependent on something specific and can then do away with them. What if someone argues that wudu was only required in ancient times because of poor hygiene and is not needed anymore to pray salah? The texts on a wali are general and an exception or abrogation to them can not be made without concrete evidence. Muhammad ﷺ married Khadijah with the consent of her wali and Moses married Tzipora with the permission of her wali, even though both were independent women.

Comment: @UmH Do divorced or widowed women also need permission from their _awliya'_?

Comment: @UmH _What if someone argues that wudu was only required in ancient times because of poor hygiene and is not needed anymore to pray salah?_ Islamic scholars have been working hard to understand the times of Prophet Muhammad PBUH and to understand the circumstances in which Quran's verses were revealed. Did any concrete evidence arise from the research of the scholars that wudu was only done to maintain good hygiene?

Comment: @UmH We Muslims place a great emphasis on understanding the context of Quran's verses. The context involves knowing the circumstances in which verses were revealed. Societies and traditions at the time of Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) and Musa (PBUH) were different than ours. If you believe we should follow verses blindly without considering the context, you will allow dangerous ideologies to flourish.

Answer (score -6):

It actually can be allowed, but with two conditions.

1. She be an escort, not a prostitute. It is haram to buy sex. However, purchasing someone's time is halal.
2. She be an independent operator, no working for a brothel, pimp, or agency. It is haram to pay for the sexual services of someone who is being employed by another in prostitution.

An independent escort has no master, and you are only paying for her time. Since you are employing her for that period of time after you have paid her, she qualifies as ma malakat aymanukum, and you do have sexual right to those, regardless of marital status. Oh, and of course they must consent to have sex with you. Rape is haram.

You could also enter into a temporary marriage with her, the duration is your period of booking, the dowry is the price for her time. Girls in this line of work tend to be rather open minded, so if you raise the latter with them ahead of time, it should not be too hard to find one willing to do that with you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Claims should be supported with evidence. How is employment equal to ownership? What about iddah \ istibra'? What about the command to not have relations with fornicators?