Voluntarily slave ? allowed or Not ? a clear ayah or Hadith can some one mention pls
Asslamwalekum WRB
my question is we do not find any Hadith that mention anything about voluntary enslavement, yes you will find some Hadith that talks about how it was offer to Zaid R.A to be free but he chooses to be a slave , even I ayah of Qur'an as much as I read and researched no such Ayah that says if some non muslim wants to be voluntarily slave for better life or getting out from a very rusty and filthy life is prohibited or any thereof this sort , can some one please enlight me , will be grateful thanks , jajakallah
thanks

Could you quote the Hadith that talks about how it was offered to Zaid R.A to be free but he chooses to be a slave as you claim? Then I will إن شاء اللّه answer your question!!!

https://www.alislam.org/articles/zaid-bin-haritha/.  not here only but your may read about this any where online or offline

Are You Qaddiyani?

Dr.Yasir Qadhi’s Seerah of The Prophet Muhammad.  ,     https://quranicquizzes.com/Quizzes/Learn/2703?courseID=6.      (3rd para)

Are You Qaddiyani Ahmed Khan?

no qadyani , lahol , not at all there are several blogs I have read I just sent that rest I read it in tafseer by taqiuddin al hilali and Dr muhsin khan

I thought you were Qadiyyani because you shared link of Alislam.org ( A website of Qadiyyani)

However, I will respond to your question within a few hours. Remember it is not Fatwa but general knowledge that will shared.

https://kashmirsufis.wordpress.com/2015/01/19/amazing-incident-of-zayd-bin-haritha-the-blessed-servant-and-son/

I am not a qadyinai wallahi , you can be sure about that , just confuse , in my questions context its no muslims we are talking about ,

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46545/is-voluntary-slavery-islamic#:~:text=Slavery%20as%20a%20whole%20is,but%20it%20may%20well%20happen.      you may read -5 para

I have answered your quesiton

This looks like you have the same misunderstanding as posted in one answer about voluntary slavery: Zaid was a slave when he entered the household of Khadija our prophet paid for him and freed him long ago before his father came asking his son back, but Zaid preferred to stay with Muhammad this is the incident, there's nothing about slavery in this incident.

وَعَلَيْكُمُ ٱلسَّلَامُ وَرَحْمَةُ ٱللَّٰهِ وَبَرَكَاتُهُ
بِسْمِ ٱللَّٰهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ
The general principle is that enslavement of Kuffar can only occur in the case of Jihad as per scholars.
However, in the case of your question regarding Kuffar surrendering themselves as slaves. Few categories must be remembered:

Harbi - Kuffar having no treaty and neither their rulers have a
treaty with Imam (Khalifah)/Amir of Muslims

Mua'ahid - Kuffar whose ruler made a peace treaty (Hudna) with Imam (Khalifah)/Amir of Muslims

Dhimmi - Kuffar who pay Jizyah and live in Dar Al Islam under Sharia.

Kuffar with Aman - Kuffar who entered with Dar Al Islam for a short
period and specific work with (Aman).


The Rule is that it is permissible to buy a Harbi Kuffar if he sells himself or even his children.
With regards to Kuffar who entered Dar Al Islam with Aman and sold his children as slaves it is permissible to buy them but there is no mention of whether it is permissible to buy that Kuffar who has aman if sell himself.
With regards to Dhimmi and Mua'ahid Kuffar it is not permissible to buy them and enslave them.
Shaykh Al Islam Ibn Tahmiyyah in his Majmu Al Fatwa was asked a question

وسئل عن شخص من الكفار في بلاد الكفار كان عليه دين باع نفسه لشخص مسلم
وقبض الثمن وأوفى به دينه وباع ابنته أيضا ورضوا بالرق وخسر عليهم التاجر
المسلم كلفة الطريق والنفقة والكسوة حتى وصلوا إلى بلاد الإسلام . فهل
يجوز بيعهم وشراؤهم ؟
He was asked about an infidel in Dar Al Kufr who was in debt. He sold
himself to a Muslim person took the price and paid off his debt. He
also sold his daughter and they were satisfied with slavery, and the
Muslim merchant bore the cost of the road, expenses, and clothing on
them until they reached the Abode of Islam. Is it permissible to buy
and sell them (slave)?

Imam Ibn Tahmiyyah Replied:

إذا دخل المسلم إلى دار الحرب بغير أمان فاشترى منهم أولادهم وخرج بهم
إلى دار الإسلام كانوا ملكا له باتفاق الأئمة وله أن يبيعهم للمسلمين
ويجوز أن يشتروا منه ويستحق على المشتري جميع الثمن .
If a Muslim enters the Abode of War without security buys their
(Harbi's) children from them and takes them out to the Abode of Islam,
they are his property, according to the Consensus of the imams, and he
has the right to sell them to the Muslims, and it is permissible for
them to buy from him, and the buyer is entitled to all the price.

Here is the fatwa of Imam Malik from Mudawanna stating the matter of Harbi who sold his children as slaves after entering Dar Al Islam with Aman. But if Kuffar have Hudna (i.e, they are Mua'ahid) then it is not permissible to buy from them.
Ref

الاشتراء من أهل الحرب أولادهم إذا نزلوا بأمان .

Imam Ibn Qayyim mentions in his book Ahkaam Ahlul Dhimmah states the reason why Umar رضي الله عنه forbade Muslims to buy slaves from Ahlul Dhimmah due to following reasons -

Dhimmis are part of Dar Al Islam and are governed and protected by
Sharia.
They sell each other and are people who pay Kharaj.

Also as per ijma the blood and wealth of Dhimmi are not permissible without just cause as they are protected due to the covenant and Jizyah that exist between them and Khalifah.
I hope your question is answered.

thank you so much for the answer , will look into it , mean while one more question , Christians , trinity believers are too can be brought , weather men or old

This whole answer has not the lightest relation to the case of Zaid ibn Haritah. I don't know if this is what OP is looking for.

OP's main focus was "Voluntary S;avery" not slavery of Zaid RA. He was freed

in that case this answer should be posted in the duplicate question since it is older.
